# Search by first name OR last name and specific related id?

Tags: java, search, jdbc, elasticsearch

I am trying to find a person by first or last name all having the same building_id.

For example someone will put in a name in a textfield which may be the first or last name. They'll all have the same building id. I cannot seem to find this in the documentation for elastic search.
My result data looks like this:

```
{
    took: 9,
    timed_out: false,
    _shards: {
        total: 5,
        successful: 5,
        failed: 0
    },
    hits: {
        total: 56,
        max_score: 1,
        hits: [
    {
        _index: "jdbc",
        _type: "jdbc",
        _id: "5",
        _score: 1,
        _source: {
            first_name: "some first name",
            last_name: "some last name",
            building_id: 1
        }
    },
...
...
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use a `term` filter with a `multi_match` query. To illustrate, first create some docs:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index"

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/person/1" -d'
{
   "first_name": "Bob",
   "last_name": "Jones",
   "building_id": 1
}'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/person/2" -d'
{
   "first_name": "Bill",
   "last_name": "Smith",
   "building_id": 1
}'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/person/3" -d'
{
   "first_name": "Joe",
   "last_name": "Williams",
   "building_id": 2
}'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/person/4" -d'
{
   "first_name": "John",
   "last_name": "Taylor",
   "building_id": 2
}'

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test_index/person/5" -d'
{
   "first_name": "Taylor",
   "last_name": "Johnson",
   "building_id": 2
}'
```

Then, if you want to search for all the "Taylor"s in Building 2, execute the following:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test_index/person/_search" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "multi_match": {
               "query": "taylor",
               "fields": [
                  "first_name",
                  "last_name"
               ]
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "term": {
               "building_id": 2
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

and you will get back the results:

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 2,
      "successful": 2,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0.94125634,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "person",
            "_id": "5",
            "_score": 0.94125634,
            "_source": {
               "first_name": "Taylor",
               "last_name": "Johnson",
               "building_id": 2
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "person",
            "_id": "4",
            "_score": 0.5906161,
            "_source": {
               "first_name": "John",
               "last_name": "Taylor",
               "building_id": 2
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is a runnable example (you will need Elasticsearch installed on your machine and running at localhost:9200):

http://be6c2e3260c3e2af000.qbox.io/gist/cc47b232ec60f09b93906a5c80028c1317dbdf28

Comment: Amazing. Why is `multi_match` in a `query` and `term` in a `filter`? And to do them both they need to be in `filtered`?

Comment: It's just how you set up a filtered query: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html. I followed the example pretty directly. The only confusing thing is that the whole construct has to go inside a "query" block.

Comment: The basic idea is that a filtered query contains a query and a filter. The filter will block out documents that don't match certain criteria, and is a little more efficient than other kinds of querying. A filtered query is not the only way to accomplish what you wanted, it was just the first to come to mind.